# How to add content place holder like a loop in asp.net. Is it allowed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages, content-pages

I have a master page called `MasterFile.master`.

I added a content place holder in master page. That content place holder holds reference to another page(`default.aspx`).

Can that reference page(`default.aspx`) hold reference to another content page? I mean like a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have as many Master pages you would like.
Look at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7.aspx
Nested ASP.NET Master Pages